# Iterating through an Object list in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I am new to play framework.

I wrote this java code to fetch details of users

```
List<Person> personsDetails = new Model.Finder(String.class, Person.class).all();
```

This is my json String

```
[{"id":"1","email":"xyz@gmail.com","password":"zxcv","login_method":"2"},
{"id":"2","email":"bvcx@gmail.com","password":"abcdef","login_method":"3"}]
```

How to get specific user by ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
You need to iterate your list `personsDetails` and check for specific id, everytime you want to fetch specific Person by id.

---

**Approach 2:**
You can prepare `Map` of id and Person -> `Map<Integer, Person>`. And use [`map.get(Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method to fetch specific person by id.

Answer (score 0):

**Used this code for getting specific user by ID.**

```
List<Person> personsDetails = new Model.Finder(String.class,Person.class).all();

HashMap<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();

for (Person product : personsDetails) {
      if (product.id == id ) {
            personMap.put("CustomerAccount", product);
      }
}
```

*Do whateveryou want to do with the new Hash Map Generated*